# Custom listview adapter size null

Tags: android, json, listview

Currently I am trying to populate with my custom listview with a JSON

It works fine with dummy data, and my json request is fine.

All this code is in onCreate view, I know we are supposed to use Async task or some sort to spawn a new thread to pull data, but I wanted to just put it here for testing purposes so I know I can pull data first.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor()).addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor()).build();

    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/response";

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
            .build();


    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "call api error");
            Log.e("Volley", e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response)  {

            try {
                if (!response.isSuccessful())
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                final String body = response.body().string();

                JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(body);


                JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("inboxMsgList");

                Log.e("Array", String.valueOf(Jarray.length()));
//Initializing my ArrayLis here I already defined it where I have my other variables defined.
                    arrMessageData = new ArrayList<>();

                JSONObject object = Jarray.getJSONObject(0);

                MessageData msg3 = new MessageData();
                msg3.setName((String) object.get("fromUser"));
                msg3.setMessage((String) object.get("message"));
                msg3.setImage(R.drawable.msgone);
                msg3.setRead(true);
                msg3.setSubject((String) object.get("subject"));

                arrMessageData.add(msg3);

                Log.e("DetailObject", msg3.getName());


                // Log.e("FullJsonReply", body.toString());
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Volley2", e.toString());
            }

        }

    });


   adapter = new CustomAdapterReferral(getActivity().getBaseContext(), arrMessageData);
    usersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The error I get is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                at com.adilpatel.vitalengine.ListAdapters.CustomAdapterReferral.getCount(CustomAdapterReferral.java:40)

Line 40 is my getCount in my Adapter

```
public int getCount() {
    return arrMessageData.size();
}
```

I put a break point right where it returns the size

[image]

Looks like the size is 1 but it still gives null pointer exception. Is it because adapter is null? What is adapter?

Edit: Here is my CustomAdapterReferral:

```
public class CustomAdapterReferral extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<MessageData> arrMessageData;
    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CustomAdapterReferral(Context mainActivity, ArrayList<MessageData> arrMessageData){


        this.arrMessageData = arrMessageData;

        context = mainActivity;


        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    public int getCount() {
        return arrMessageData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView referralName;
        ImageView referralImage;
        TextView referralMessage;


    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_referral, null);


        holder.referralName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.referralName);
        holder.referralImage =(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.referralImage);
        holder.referralMessage= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.referralMessage);

        holder.referralMessage.setText("" + arrMessageData.get(position).getMessage());
        holder.referralName.setText("" + arrMessageData.get(position).getName());
        holder.referralImage.setImageResource(arrMessageData.get(position).getImage());

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you edit your question to show the class `CustomAdapterReferral`?

Comment: @quidproquo updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use handler

```
 private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    adapter = new CustomAdapterReferral(getActivity().getBaseContext(), arrMessageData);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d("TAG", msg.what + " ? ");
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

and in OkHttpClient use this

```
 @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response)  {
  //YOUR CODE
 //END
handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

}
```

Comment: Works! But can you explain a little why it didnt work the way I had it. It seems like it should even going through the debugger.

Comment: Because with the method proposed by @ARH you make sure that your code is executed after you get your request response.

Comment: Your code did't work because this var "arrMessageData" wasn't ready at the time you wanted to use it (cause async thread), so this method waits for it to be ready then uses it.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the `Callback` interface to `enqueue()`. Your `arrMessageData` is initialized in `onResponse()` of the Callback - but this callback-method is called after you create your adapter, so the ArrayList you pass to the Constructor is `null`: That causes the NullPointerException.